# How to send notification to specific user in Expo/Laravel

Tags: laravel, react-native, expo, react-native-push-notification, laravel-notification

I have an Expo app with a Laravel backend and I want to send notifications to the app. But the condition is that only a specific user can receive it.
I installed the Following library [Exponent Notifications](https://github.com/Alymosul/laravel-exponent-push-notifications)
I've Installed `expo-notifications` as well
But I don't know How it works, How I can listen to the notification channel and How to send Notification from backend.

Answer (score 0):

With Expo you don't get to pick the push notification service according to you, you can try Firebase Cloud messaging or One Signal, but I don't think you can do it only by your Laravel Backend

Comment: So, Can I send notifications to a specific user with Firebase Cloud Messaging or One Signal?

Comment: You need to collect device token for every device and store it, and send notifications to device tokens